# Create list of checkboxes (automatically) for separate values, not multivalue, in Access 2010

Tags: microsoft-access

I'm trying to create a form whereby I can add multiple values to a table. I want to select the values using a list of check boxes, but there are a lot of values- is there anyway to automatically generate check boxes based on all the possible values in a column? I see how it is possible to create a multi-value from a checkboxlist, but this is not what I want.

The column is 'Skills', and examples of values I want to add- several per individual- would be things like 'sewing', 'carpentry', 'arts and crafts' etc.

New skills will be added in the future, so i want the list on the forms to update to include the new skill with a new textbox. To me it sounds like it should be an easy enough thing, but there is no option I can see for it.

Answer (score 0):

A subform which contains a checkbox and a txtbox for 'skills' would solve the problem. This would mean that you can have one or more skills listed, with a checkbox next to each of them.